# Detect when pi is outputting sound

Tags: gpio, audio

Is there a way to detect if sound is playing on the pi, then turn on GPIO pin if it is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "if audio is playing"?  Without knowing that the question is unanswerable.

Comment: I mean if another application is currently playing audio. For example if vlc is playing an audio file in the background.

Comment: @AbeZukor: You would somehow need to monitor those applications via a plugin or something similar.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?